# Opposite complex structure on Kaehler manifold

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry, linear-algebra, complex-geometry, kahler-manifolds

Let $(M,J)$ be a Kaehler manifold. How can one describe the opposite complex structure? What is the precise definition of the opposite complex structure? Can one describe the opposite complex structure in terms of $J$?

Comment: Do you mean the *conjugate* complex structure instead?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The opposite complex structure is $-J$.